# Api-Platform and GraphQl - how do I get the data from a special operation?

Tags: symfony, graph, annotations, api-platform.com

I recently started working with Api Platform and Graphql on a new project. Usually I worked with Symfony and REST Api. So now I've created a special operation (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#recommended-method) and it is working with Rest Api. But how do I create my Graphql Query to get this data? 
I read a lot, googled more and tried out a lot. Nothing works. I am totally new to Graphql. So it would be very very helpful if you could give me an exact example :D

Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Component\EntityTrait\TimestampableEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Loggable\Loggable;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Timestampable;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use App\Controller\DocumentVersion;

/**
 * @ApiResource(itemOperations={
 *     "versions"={
 *         "method"="GET",
 *         "path"="/documents/{id}/versions",
 *         "controller"="App\Controller\DocumentVersion::getVersions"
 *     },
 *     "version"={
 *         "method"="GET",
 *         "path"="/documents/{id}/version/{version}",
 *         "controller"="App\Controller\DocumentVersion::getVersion"
 *     },
 *     "get"
 * })
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class Document implements \App\Contract\Entity\Document, Timestampable, Loggable
{ 
// usual getters+setters 
}
```

DocumentVersion is my "Controller" that contains both methods getVersion and getVersions. Calling both paths with Rest Api is working. 
But how to call with the graphql ui at localhost:8080/graphql ?

I tried this:

```
query getDocument {
  document(id: "documents/3/versions") {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

and a lot of other things, but nothing works. 
Documentation is not yet given by Api Platform. 
Hope anyone can help me, project is short of time (of course).
Thanks
Jule